# Lemma on locally finite open covers

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I came across this lemma in Lee's 'Introduction to Smooth Manifolds'. The lemma seems simple enough to prove, but I just can't seem to prove it. It's frustrating me because I know it must be simple.

The lemma is: An open cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ of a topological space $X$ is locally finite if and only if each $U_{\alpha}$ intersects $U_{\beta}$ for only finitely many $\beta$.

Lee then asks to Give a counterexample if the sets of the cover are not assumed to be open.

Does anyone have any glaringly obvious things to point out I'm missing?

I have thought about trying to prove the necessary statement via contradiction. Ie suppose the open cover is locally finite but assume there exists a $U_{\alpha}$ such that $U_{\alpha}$ intersects infinitely many $U_{\beta}$-s. The required result would follow easily (I think) if I was able to show that there is a common point $p$ in this infinite intersection' - but I'm not sure if I can conclude this.

Comment: Where is this in the manifolds book?  I don't think this is true.

Comment: If the $U_\beta$ all consist of exactly one point, the condition is satisfied by the covering is not locally finite unless the manifold is discrete.

Comment: Here are the errata in case you want to check: http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Smooth/errata.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've stated is not true.  Take, for example the topological space $\mathbb R \times (0, 3) \subseteq \mathbb R^2$.  The following open cover is locally finite but the first set intersects infinitely many others:

- Take the set $\mathbb R \times (0, 2)$
- Take the sets $(n, n + 2) \times (1, 3)$ for all $n$.

I think what you're referring to is Problem 1-4 on page 31.  There you're asked to prove the lemma you've stated under the assumption that the sets in the open cover are *precompact*.

Comment: Thanks, I was using the old edition...

Comment: @beedge89: The lemma you stated is not in the first edition of my book either. Are you using one of the pirated early drafts that keep floating around the internet? If so, you should be aware that those versions are full of errors. I wouldn't recommend that anyone trust what they read there.

Comment: Apparently I was. Busted. Though my university does give me free access anyway so I don't feel too guilty. I have the latest edition now. I guess I'll take this opportunity to say your books are great! So thank you!